# apache installation via xampp

Tags: configuration, server, xampp, bitnami

I am pretty much new in this field. I have installed Bitnami.C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.7-0\apache2\htdocs this is my root folder and I have done many work done in that folder.   They are all working fine...but I realized that I need Xampp so I downloaded Xampp and the problem faced in Apache saying

> [mysql]    Problem detected!
>    [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by "C:\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.7-0\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --
>               defaults-file=C:\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.7-0\mysql\my.ini wampstackMySQL"!        [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>   [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

How should I fix this...and what caused the problem? is that because of Apache server I installed via Bitnami? configuration issue right? if so

How should I config Xampp without touching or changing root folder I am afraid of messing up the current works.

Comment: In addition to that above question, one thing I want to know is my localhost port is http://localhost:81
why xampp say "port 3306"?? I want to know!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi Bitnami engineer here,

The control panel of XAMPP is showing that error because the default port of MySQL is in used. You can check the process that is using the 3306 port by clicking in the Netstat button in the control panel.

Once you know the process that is using that port, you can either stop that process or modify the port that MySQL uses in the `C:\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.7-0\mysql\my.ini` file.

In case the default Apache port (80) is not used, Apache will start without throwing any error message.

Regards,
Jota

Comment: Hi Martos thanks but How should I modify the my.ini? it shows that 3306 is being used by Mysql..should I change it to 80?? very sorry but pls advise me to the last

Comment: I changed 3306 to 80 in my.ini  and it still causes the problem so I stopped all in the manage server tab in the bitnami.... And I tried to stop all and it shows MySql is stopped but Appache is running on green...

Comment: Hi @SonnyCho, you can select any free port in the 1-65535 range. As I mentioned, you can check the used ports using the "Netstat" tool in the control panel of XAMPP. For instance, you can use the 3307 port when starting MySQL in case that port is free in your computer.